# Array Index to Matrix Index

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix, command-line

I have a `byte array` that is indexed by a single index `i`. But this array will be presented on the screen as an `array of array` (not a matrix since not all the lines have the same dimensions). And with the arrow keys I be able to "surf" these elements of the "matrix". The selected element will have a different background color. To do this I will need the `rows` and `columns` of byte I want to highlight.

So I need help on formula to convert a single index for a row and a column.

I have already created the logic for the keys, ie, when it is possible to move in a certain direction, just need to show on the screen.

The lenght of a complete line is 8 bytes.

In this case the array is:

```
unsigned char test[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x07, 0x21, 0x09, 0x0A};
```

And it would appear this way:

[image]

Comment: Your example is incomplete. If the right edge truly is jagged, you must have extra information about the line lengths. If you always have 8 bytes per line except the last, that's a much simpler case.

Comment: @unwind question edited

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the index knowing the Column, Row and line length you would simply do:

```
I = Row * LineLenght + Column;
```

The inverse is the following:

```
Row = I / LineLength; // Integer division 
Column = I % LineLength; // Remainder of the division of I by LineLength
```

This is basic arithmetic :)

You have to make sure you never fall off the array size.

Comment: tip: use "//" in divisions that require an integer result, in order to make it future-proof.

Answer (score 2):

You should use modus and divison for this.
For example if you want to have 7 elements in a line, to get the first index you need to divide by 7, to get the second index, mod by 7.

so 10 would become 1, 3

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to decide, first of all, how many columns you want to have (call this number X). So you will have Y rows (all complete, 1 or 0 incomplete). Now when you want to the convert an index i: row = i / Y, column = i % Y.

Comment: Uh, I think you meant `X` somewhere in the end there. It doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Yep, it should be X and not Y on both formulas